# Android Studio Error Duplicate Resource

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':fiesCabs:mergeDebugResources'. C:\Users\tony\AndroidstudioProjects\Fies-Cabs\fiesCabs\src\main\res\values\themes_apptheme.xml: Error: Duplicate resources: C:\Users\tony\AndroidstudioProjects\Fies-Cabs\fiesCabs\src\main\res\values\themes_apptheme.xml:style/AppTheme, C:\Users\tony\AndroidstudioProjects\Fies-Cabs\fiesCabs\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:style/AppTheme

Error:Error: Duplicate resources: C:\Users\tony\AndroidstudioProjects\Fies-Cabs\fiesCabs\src\main\res\values\themes_apptheme.xml:style/AppTheme, C:\Users\tony\AndroidstudioProjects\Fies-Cabs\fiesCabs\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:style/AppTheme
```

Error shown in android studio while building the project

**themes_apptheme.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Generated with http://android-holo-colors.com -->
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/_AppTheme"/>

 <style name="_AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextAppTheme</item>

<item name="android:textColorHighlight">#9933b5e5</item>

<item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/AutoCompleteTextViewAppTheme</item>

<item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBoxAppTheme</item>

<item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/RadioButtonAppTheme</item>

<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonAppTheme</item>

<item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButtonAppTheme</item>

<item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerAppTheme</item>

<item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItemAppTheme</item>

<item name="android:progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/ProgressBarAppTheme</item>

<item name="android:seekBarStyle">@style/SeekBarAppTheme</item>

<item name="android:ratingBarStyle">@style/RatingBarAppTheme</item>

<item name="android:ratingBarStyleIndicator">@style/RatingBarBigAppTheme</item>

<item name="android:ratingBarStyleSmall">@style/RatingBarSmallAppTheme</item>

<item name="android:buttonStyleToggle">@style/ToggleAppTheme</item>

<item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/ListViewAppTheme</item>

<item name="android:listViewWhiteStyle">@style/ListViewAppTheme.White</item>

<item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemAppTheme</item>

 </style>

</resources>
```

not familiar with android studio just imported the project from eclipse  while it works fine with eclipse if there is any prerequisites to build in android studio please inform me

Answer (score 39):

You have the same resource `style/AppTheme` in two files, `values/styles.xml` and `values/themes_apptheme.xml`. Rename or remove the other.

Comment: for it was app_name and action_settings was there in both string.xml and styles.xml, it did resolve after removing from one xml.

Comment: In my case app_name was redefined in different modules.

Answer (score 7):

After using Android Studio to create a new empty Activity using the new Activity wizard, the layout's XML file `res/layout/myactivity_layout.xml` was auto-generated, but Android Studio ALSO silently added `/res/values/dimens.xml`.

I already have a `/res/values/dimen.xml` file where I defined my various dimensions.

Android Studio added 2 new dimension keys to these files (without checking for conflicts) and sure enough, the keys for the 2 new dimensions were already defined in my `dimen.xml` file, so my Gradle build failed.

I assume the reason Android Studio added `dimens.xml` is because it didn't recognize my `dimen.xml` file existed.  And the reason Android Studio auto-added new dimensions to `dimens.xml` is to adhere to Android's style conventions for Material Design (which I'm not adhering to for my project).

I would much prefer if Android Studio did not auto-generate problems without checking first!

I removed the extraneously added `dimens.xml` files and must now either rename my `dimen.xml` to `dimens.xml` or never use the new Activity Wizard again.  Thanks Android.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have created dynamically in your gradle a res value. Check it and if exists delete it